# Can I manualy copy SOLR index files?

Tags: solr, replication

I have a cluster of 3 sharded SOLR 4.1. There is a replicated cluster but the data is quite out of synced. I have stopped polling on those secondary nodes for a long time.

Now I want to start the replication again but I'm afraid it would take too long to replicate 400GB index data on each node.

If I manually copy over the index files from the master to the slave node, will it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should work just fine - as long as you don't write to the index while copying it (or copy it from a snapshot). In fact, that's what the replication does in the background (by replicating the segment files that needs replicating).

In older versions of Solr the replication was just shell scripts triggered to copy the index to other servers after an update happened.

Comment: Thank mate, let me try this weekend

Comment: I'm using rsync to copy index files from Master to Slave. I verified and saw that the files are copied successfully, the number of files are equal but when I perform the query on Slave, it doesn't return latest result as on Master. Should I delete the file replication.properties on SLAVE?

Comment: @MatsLindh, When you say "as long as you don't write to the index while copying it" you mean write to the index at the source or at the destination ?

Comment: @Viraj Just that there shouldn't be a commit or optimize while manually copying the files - you don't want the files to change mid copy (so that one of the files are from a different index version than the others)

Comment: @MatsLindh would that cause a failure(if there is an ongoing commit). I am trying to implement something similar to this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34140384/copy-solr-hdfs-data-to-another-cluster

Comment: @Viraj If you're unsure - create hardlinks or a snapshot of the files, and then copy them - if anything writes a new file while you're copying them, you'll still work on the old version. I'm not familiar with HDFS so I'm not sure if you have any versioning or snapshotting available, but I'd think so?

Comment: @MatsLindh Can you copy index files from multiple shards into one shard ?

Comment: @Viraj No. You'll have to use the `IndexMergeTool` - see [Merging Indexes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Merging+Indexes). But please - ask a new question if you have a new question, don't hijack an existing answer.