# Copy Solr HDFS Data to another Cluster

Tags: hadoop, solr, hdfs, cloudera

I have a solr cloud (v 4.10) installation that sits on top of Cloudera (CDH 5.4.2) HDFS with 3 solr instances each hosting a shard of each core. 
I am looking for a way to incrementally copy the solr data from our production cluster to our development cluster. There are 3 cores but I am only interested in copying one of them.

I have tried to use the Solr replication - backup and restore but that doesn't seem to load anything into the dev cluster.

```
http://host:8983/solr/core/replication?command=backup&location=/solr_transfer&name=core-name
http://host:8983/solr/core/replication?command=restore&location=/solr_transfer&name=core-name
```

I also tried to snapshot the /solr dir in the hdfs prod clusters and use hadoop disctp to copy the files but the solr indexer deletes some of the files so the distcp job fails.

```
hadoop distcp hftp://prod:50070/solr/* hdfs://dev:8020/solr/
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer to this ?

Comment: no - i currently: (1) stop the dev cluster (2) copy the unix files across using rsync (3) start the cluster up which is far from ideal but it does work

Comment: backup & restore doesn't work with solr 4.10. how did u work finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying this is the solution we worked out.
- Initialise solr in the second environment with all the collections in the same way as the primary.
- Take a snapshot of HDFS
- Use hadoop hdfs -cp to copy the data up to the checkpoint
After the first run the copy job will be quick as you are only copying the increments.

Answer (score 1):

please follow below steps to create snapshot of solr_hdfs folder and move the same on another cluster

1.Allow snapshot

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfsadmin -allowSnapshot /user/solr/SolrCollectionName
```

2.Create snapshot with a specific name

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop dfs -createSnapshot /user/solr/SolrCollectionName/ snapshotName
```

3. To list to snapshot directory

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/solr/solrcollectionName/.snapshot
```

4. To copy, execute below command

```
 sudo -u solr hadoop distcp hdfs://NNIP1:8020/user/solr/collectionName/.snapshot/SanpshotName  hdfs://NNIP2:8020/user/solr
```

5. To restore snapshot

```
sudo -u solr hadoop fs -cp /user/solr/SanpshotName/* /user/solr/SolrcollectionName/
```